# C - getting pressed KeyCode (NOT stdio)

Tags: c, keycode

I'm trying to write a little program (in C), which writes every pressed Key I'm pressing into a .txt-file (and yes, it's a keylogger).

But I don't want to use the stdio, because I'm using `FreeConsole();`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *datei;
    datei = fopen("test.txt","w+");
    if (datei == NULL) exit(1);
    FreeConsole();
    while(1)
    {
        c =    ???      ;              //get KeyCode of pressed key
        fprintf(datei, "%c",c);
        if (c == 27)
        {
              break;
        }
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    fclose(datei);
    return(0);
}
```

Hope I made it clear (*hope*)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with only the standard library. The I/O functions that don't specify an explicit `FILE*` found in the standard library get their data from the standard input (`stdin`).

Thus, the standard input does not necessarily have to be attached to a terminal, from which you could retrieve actual keystrokes. You have to look into your operating system's documentation and APIs for that.

Comment: So does it mean my programm maybe runs on Windows7 but not on Windows8?

Comment: No. What I wrote has nothing to do with Windows at all.